# Clone stamp tool active area too small

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm not an expert in photoshop, but I noticed the active area of the stamp tool is much smaller than the circle.

I'm not sure what I have changed (possibly by mistake) and do not see any options to reset to the default brush.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a question about graphic design, but about the workings of a software (i.e. Photoshop). Please review the help files for said software, as well as the Adobe fora.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's linked to Brush Hardness.
Key command Mac -   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>[</kbd>  or  <kbd>]</kbd> 
Windows presumably  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  instead

Examples
[I can't get a screenshot including the brush itself - it's the size of the first sample image]

Hardness 100

[image]

[image]

Hardness 0

[image]

[image]

<sup>The image, btw, was from the Photography SE, so already in the SE domain - a problem someone had with colour aberration.

I don't normally publish photos with that much distortion going on ;-)</sup>

Comment: is it possible that, regardless of hardness, the active area is much smaller than the circle? it seems to me like the first example (100 hardness) where only the area around the center of the circle is used

Comment: It fades out from the centre, so at anything less that 100% opacity, 100% flow, it likely looks like it's not filling the area